# Embedded plot is not displayed correctly in Firefox

Tags: html, css, r, ggplotly

I created a plot in R with ggplotly and saved it as html.

```
fig1 <- ggplotly(g.1.1, tooltip = c("text"), dynamicTicks = TRUE) %>% 
  style(hoverinfo = "none", traces = c(1,4,6,8,10,12,14,16,18,20,22,24,26,28,30,32,34,36))  %>%
  config(displayModeBar = T, locale = "de")  %>% 
  layout(hoverlabel = list(align = "left"),
         legend = list(orientation = "h", x = 0.3, y = -0.15),
         hovermode = "y unified",
         hoverdistance = 2,
         showlegend = TRUE ,
         xaxis = list(autorange=FALSE,
                      range = c(as.Date("2020-08-31"),k.DownDat),
                      showgrid = F, ticklen = 10,
                      ticks = "outside",
                      tickmode = "array",
                      tickformat = '%e.%b',
                      ticktext = labels,
                      tickangle = 0,
                      title = ""),
         yaxis = list(autorange = FALSE, 
                      range = c(0,k.MaxWert_proTag + 100), 
                      tickformat = "digits"
         ))
```

First I embedded the plot with `iframe` on our website. This caused the legend entries to be displayed overlapped. After that I embedded the plot with `embed`. The legend entries were displayed correctly in Chrome and Edge, but not in Firefox.
Any ideas what could cause the proplem in Firefox and how I could solve this?

This didn't work properly:

```
<iframe src="https://path/Inzidenz7T_CheckLegend.html"  scrolling="no"  frameBorder="0" width="950" height="600" marginwidth="0" marginheight = "0" hspace="0" vspace="0" style="padding: 0px; display: block"></iframe>
```

This worked for Chrome and Edge, but not for Firefox:

```
<embed style="border: none;" src="https://path/Inzidenz7T_CheckLegend.html" dpi="300"width="880" height="600" marginwidth="0" marginheight = "0" hspace="0" vspace="0" style="padding: 0px display: block/>
```

This is how it should look like:
[image: Edge]

This is how it looks in Firefox:
[image: Firefox]

Comment: What do you see when you inspect the 'Neu...' using yur browser's dev tools? You should be able to check exactly who/where the styling is being set.

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41819685/opening-plotly-offline-webpage-in-firefox

Comment: There might be some crucial webkit css which is ignored by Firefox

Comment: @A Haworth: Do you mean this: 
```<text class="legendtext user-select-none" text-anchor="start" style="font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 10.6268px; fill: rgb(0, 0, 0); fill-opacity: 1; white-space: pre;" x="40" y="4.144458281444598" data-unformatted="Neu gemeldet" data-math="N">Neu gemeldet</text>```

Comment: @danlooo Thanks for the hint. It goes in the right direction, but the suggested solution (using self-contained = false) doesn't work.
I already use this for saving the plot: 
 ```saveWidget(partial_bundle(fig1_2), paste0(outputdir,"WEB_public/Test_g.1.1.html"), selfcontained = F, libdir = "Test_g.1.1") ```